# Generating paper-tab using a template not working in IE

Tags: polymer

The following code works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE I have to click a tab twice to get the tab to change or respond to the click.  I'm thinking it may have something to do with creating paper-tabs in the template.  Is there a workaround to get this to function correctly in IE? I'm running 0.51.

```
<paper-tabs id="papertabs" selected="{{selected}}">

  <paper-tab name="all">All</paper-tab>

   <template id="papertabstemplate" repeat="{{cat in categories}}">
        <template if="{{ cat.group == group }}">
            <paper-tab name="{{cat.category}}">{{cat.category}}</paper-tab>
        </template>
   </template>

</paper-tabs>
```